# Microsoft RemoteApp Active Session

Tags: remote-desktop-services, remoteapp, windows

In Microsoft Remote App documentation i found that when a connection between server and client lost because of network fault the session remains active for 20 seconds to let the client if it can connect back to the server,i need to know how can i decrease or increase this time??

Comment: This question was already discussed [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/176560/remoteapp-idle-time-before-disconnecting), please, check it.

Comment: yes you'r right

Answer (score 0):

The same settings should apply to RemoteApp.

[Configure Timeout and Reconnection Settings for Remote Desktop Services Sessions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272.aspx)

> To specify timeout and reconnection settings for a remote session
>
> 1. On the RD Session Host server, open Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration. To open Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration, click Start, point to Administrative Tools, point to Remote Desktop Services, and then click Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration.
> 2. Under Connections, right-click the name of the connection, and then click Properties.
> 3. In the Properties dialog box for the connection, on the Sessions tab, select the following options as necessary:
> 4. Select the Override user settings check box, and then set timeout settings for End a disconnected session, Active session limit, and Idle session limit.
> 5. Select the Override user settings check box, and then select one of the following reconnection settings: Disconnect from session or End session.
> 6. Click OK. Changes to timeout and reconnection settings are not applied to sessions that are connected when the change is made. The changes will take effect the next time the user establishes a new connection to the RD Session Host server.